# If $g(x)$ be the inverse of $f(x)$ then prove that $2g''=3g^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $$f(x)=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^3}}$$ Prove that $$2g''=3g^2$$ given $g(x)$ is inverse of $f(x)$.

I tried of applying Newton-Leibnitz both sides but could not succeed as the variable is $x$ on the left and $t$ on the right.

How to do this?

Comment: The variable on the right is $x$, not $t$. The expression on the right depends only on $x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hints**:

1. If $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$, then $g'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(g(x))}$
2. If $f(x)=\int_{0}^x h(t)dt$, then $f'(x)=h(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer. A bit off topic question... can you please suggest what level of students (I mean like highschool, undergrad, grad etc.) do you expect to solve this question?

Comment: @tatan This seems like something that would appear in an undergrad exam as one of the easier questions, or in a high school test as an extra-credits type of homework question.

Comment: Thanks fo the response ;-)